# how to insert the text in the editor in the TextAdornment template in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I follow the steps in this page http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/12/09/building-and-publishing-an-extension-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx

I create a TextAdornment project and a search box. I wan to do some different in this page. I want to query a link , get a list in the WPF user control and then write the info into the editor back. so the question is I do not know how to write the text back into the editor in seachbox(WPF user control)?
I searched a lot, and get a way to use the code look like this:

```
IVsTextManager txtMgr = (IVsTextManager)GetService(typeof(SVsTextManager));
        IVsTextView vTextView = null;
        int mustHaveFocus = 1;
        txtMgr.GetActiveView(mustHaveFocus, null, out vTextView);
        IVsUserData userData = vTextView as IVsUserData;
        if (userData == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            IWpfTextViewHost viewHost;
            object holder;
            Guid guidViewHost = DefGuidList.guidIWpfTextViewHost;
            userData.GetData(ref guidViewHost, out holder);
            viewHost = (IWpfTextViewHost)holder;
            return viewHost;
        }
```

However, the method "GetService" also said not found. I think the reason is this method is for VSPackage. and it is not suitable for Adornment project.

Please help to point how the write the text back into the editor from WPF user control. Thanks!

======================================================================================

**Solution:**
when creating the SearchBox(WPF User Control), pass through the IWpfTextView to WPF control.and then,it is possible to use this in SearchBox.xaml.cs. Also need to be aware to use the Dispatcher function to keep the UI thread is the active one.

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {

            ITextEdit edit = _view.TextBuffer.CreateEdit();
            ITextSnapshot snapshot = edit.Snapshot;

            int position = snapshot.GetText().IndexOf("gist:");
            edit.Delete(position, 5);
            edit.Insert(position, "billmo");
            edit.Apply();
        }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have there is if you're in a package and you are trying to figure out what view is currently active...it's overkill for what you're trying to do.

Assuming you started from the TextAdornment template, the adornment object is given an IWpfTextView in the constructor. (If not, you probably have an implementation of `IWpfTextCreationListener.TextViewCreated` which got it and you need to thread it through.) The IWpfTextView derives ITextView which has a property ITextBuffer. From here, you can call CreateEdit() and edit text from there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think I need to clarify my question. After TextAdornment template created, indeed, there are two classes, "TextAdornment.cs" and "TextAdornmentFactory.cs". And then,following the link in my question, I add a WPF User Control in this project.  My question, I want to trigger an action(add some text into editor) from this WPF user control, which I think my code should write in the class of this WPF user control. so here is the question. How can I add the text into the editor from this WPF control.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the text in the editor and copy it to the WPF control, or you want the WPF control to be able to insert text back into the editor?

Comment: I want the WPF control to be able to insert text back into editor

Comment: OK, then I did answer the right way. Which part is confusing you so I can clarify it?

Comment: how can I get IWpfTextView in the my created WPF user control?

Comment: The editor gives you the object in the TextAdornmentFactory, and the default templates pass that through to the TextAdornment. You just need to keep passing the object along through the constructor to your user control.